# Xcode creates archive instead of IPA

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, archive, ipa

I am trying to create an ipa file (Product->Archive->Share) but Xcode produces just archive file.

It worked well few days ago. I was always getting working ipa but now I can't make it to produce ipa (when I click on share in archive I can't sign the code). I have added subproject into main project within few past days (CorePlot-CocoaTouch). I am no one hundred sure it can relates.

Answer (score 13):

If you've added a static library, they get installed by default now. This is not okay for iPhone applications. Go to the project file and select the static library's target. Under `Build Settings`, go to the `Deployment` section and change the `Skip Install` setting to `YES`. Since Xcode 4, it is now `NO` by default, which will break your IPA (since the only binary you can install legally is the application binary itself).

You may have to switch from the `Basic` view to the `All` view to see this setting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already did this (set all "skip installs" I found to yes) but with same result. It still offers me archive without chance to share it as ipa.

Comment: @Engeor Then something else is still getting installed. Take a look inside the original archive that got created (or even the new one that it makes). The only thing in there should be your app bundle. Find out what else is getting in there and you will have a clue where to look next.

Comment: The only difference between old archive that worked and new archive that isn't is folder with header files of CorePlot. Apart of this there is only one app file. I am lost :-(

Comment: @Engeor That's the problem! Dont install the header files. Change them to project or private and you'll be set.

Comment: Thank you. Meantime I have included coreplot as a static library, not the the project what solved the problem. But thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 8):

Since the answer that worked for me is buried in the comments, I thought I'd bring it to the top. In my case, changing the header files for the static library to Project fixed the issue.

To do this, select your library target, then go to Build Phases > Copy Headers and move the header files from Public to Project.

Answer (score 2):

One who has tried all other answers and had no luck the please check this check box, hope it'll help (did the trick for me xcode 6.0.1)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 5 the same error occurs if you have multiple targets and wrong checkmarks in Manage Schemes. Then Xcode puts 2 binaries into 1 Generic Archive. This does not affect checked in files into e.g. git!

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are all probably right, but didn’t help in my case. I spent hours on this and finally rebooted. Then I once more got the application archive I had gotten a week ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you include a project that produces a static library, try checking the option "copy only when installing".  This stopped Xcode from including the static library inside my application archive.  I used Xcode 6.3.2.